# iTextSharp pdfWriter.GetInstance error

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using the iTextSharp pdf creater, I've used it in the past without issue, but on the newest project when I set the GetInstance call, I get an error. I'm working in Visual Studios C#

My code is:

```
Document ManagementReportDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 15f, 15f, 75f, 75f);

FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Pdf/PdfSample") + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyHHmmss") + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(ManagementReportDoc, file);
```

...

Visual Studio reports that 'The best overloaded method match for 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(iTextSharp.tesxt.Document, System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments'

I've tried using the dll and the class files and neither makes a difference. When I add further code such as 'ManagementReportDoc.Open();' I get further errors 'Document' does not contain a definition for 'Open'. I believe I've declared the correct using libraries.

It's frustrating that it works on two other projects, but nothing I do seems to get it to work on these projects.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

G

Comment: Try using fully resolved class names like `iTextSharp.text.Document`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but makes no difference. - G

Comment: Sorry, I initially only added it to the line with the error, but when I added it to the other lines of code using the iTextsharp class it worked! Thanks for the prompt, finding an alternative would have been a real nightmare I didn't need.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to Chris Haas for replying in the comments and essentially providing me with the answer.

Using the fully resolved class names resolved the error, so now my code reads

```
iTextSharp.text.Document ManagementReportDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 15f, 15f, 75f, 75f);

FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/pdf/management-report/") + "management-report-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMMM-yy") + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(ManagementReportDoc, file); // PdfWriter.GetInstance(ManagementReportDoc, file);

ManagementReportDoc.Open();
```

and it all seems to work.

Thanks again Chris