# iTextSharp GetInstance - NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, itext, nullreferenceexception

Hope someone can spot the problem.  I'm saving a DataGridView to PDF, and getting an error on the GetInstance line of code below.  I've verified that sfd.FileName has a valid value and stream is not null.

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream (sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create)) {

   iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc =  new iTextSharp.text.Document (PageSize.A4, 10f, 20f, 20f, 10f);

   PdfWriter.GetInstance (pdfDoc, stream);   // NullReferenceException on this line.
   pdfDoc.Open();
   pdfDoc.Add (pdfTable);
   pdfDoc.Close();
   stream.Close();
}
```

Full method code:

```
private void SavePDF () {

    if (grdKeywordSearch.Rows.Count > 0) {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
        sfd.FileName = "Output.pdf";
        bool fileError = false;
        if (sfd.ShowDialog () == DialogResult.OK) {
            if (File.Exists (sfd.FileName)) {
                try {
                    File.Delete (sfd.FileName);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    fileError = true;
                    MessageBox.Show ("It wasn't possible to write the data to the disk." + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            if (!fileError) {
                try {
                    PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable (grdKeywordSearch.Columns.Count);
                    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
                    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in grdKeywordSearch.Columns) {
                        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
                        pdfTable.AddCell (cell);
                    }

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdKeywordSearch.Rows) {
                        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
                            pdfTable.AddCell (cell.Value.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream (sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create)) {

                        iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc =  new iTextSharp.text.Document (PageSize.A4, 10f, 20f, 20f, 10f);

                        PdfWriter.GetInstance (pdfDoc, stream);
                        pdfDoc.Open();
                        pdfDoc.Add (pdfTable);
                        pdfDoc.Close();
                        stream.Close();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show ("Data Exported Successfully.", "Info");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    MessageBox.Show ("Error :" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show ("Nothing to export.", "Info");
    }

}
```

Stack Trace added via this code, one line before the error:

```
Console.WriteLine (new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString());
```

> The thread 0x4508 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x6078 has
> exited with code 0 (0x0).    at Clarity.frmClarity.SavePDF()    at
> Clarity.frmClarity.btnSavePDF_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
> Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
> dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at Clarity.Program.Main()

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Hi, mkl.  Just added to my original post.

Comment: You may need to give fully qualified path: iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(). My guess is the compiler thinks PdfWriter is supposed to be an object that was not initialized. See here: [iTextSharp pdfWriter.GetInstance error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884908/itextsharp-pdfwriter-getinstance-error)

Comment: I did that, but still get the same error. :(

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, although I do not understanding it.  You have to turn on "Just My Code" under debugging options.  The error went away after I did that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048766/what-is-just-my-code

I don't know much about .NET, but maybe you are running your code in Debug mode? And Visual Studio is a bit weird about that?

Can you reproduce the issue in JetBrains Rider? That's an IDE that I am more familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS 2022.  The ' turn on "Just My Code" ' worked for me too.
In my case, it was the PdfStamper that complained:

```
var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(pdfOutputFilePath, FileMode.Create));
```

An empty file was getting created.  Also, when at the breakpoint, due the exception, in the immediate window I was able to assign  new FileStream(pdfOutputFilePath, FileMode.Create)  to a variable, and .Write(byte) and .Close(), so it was not a 'permissions' problem.

Also, the app worked fine when I ran the .exe from the bin folders, and also ran fine when I put similar code in LinqPad 6 & 7.  I also tried running VS "as administrator", and that did not work.

It seems that the same issue was reported here (so I'll post the answer there too)
[iTextSharp null reference error when using PdfStamper with all PDFs and non-null stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523079/itextsharp-null-reference-error-when-using-pdfstamper-with-all-pdfs-and-non-null)