# How to write a pdf using pdf writer in I.textSharp when it says null reference exception

Tags: c#, image, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

```
var file = new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create);
using (var document = new Document())
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, file);
}
```

this is throwing null reference exception in my system

Comment: At which point is the exception thrown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iTextSharp pdfWriter.GetInstance error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884908/itextsharp-pdfwriter-getinstance-error)

Comment: what is output.pdf. you should include complete path of file like "C:\output.pdf"

Comment: PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, file); here exception is thrown

Comment: could you provide a full exception including the inner call stack? Because the code you provided is fine and works

Comment: Actual code is working fine but the GetInstance method is taking bit longer time to load since the file is not loading it is throwing the error , i dont know to use await and async here.

Comment: Yes "output.pdf" is the full reference for the file

Comment: First of all, please *provide a full exception including the inner call stack* as @Adalyat has asked for. If you provide no details, the only answers you'll get are like the generic one Fildor's comment points to. Furthermore you say you *dont know to use await and async here* - you simply don't do so; iText does not make use of these asynchronous constructs.